# Variables in cURL

Tags: linux, bash, variables, curl, gnuwin32

As you all know tokens can be very long strings and become a hassle to copy and past over and over.

How can I store the token string as a variable and call it when I need it in cURL

example

token: "ABCDefG"

I want to be able to call something like:

```
curl -L --silent --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=${token}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside a bash script, can't you put the token in a variable, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

token="ABCDef"
curl -L --silent --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$token"
```

Now in the bash script whenever you need to use the token, you just need to use the variable `"$token"` (remember to enclose the variable in double quotes).

Or you could set an environment variable:

```
export token=ABCDef
```

but it's not an elegant solution

Comment: You say" (remember to enclose the variable in double quotes)." but you don't do that in the curl example you gave.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the token in an array

```
tokens=("ABCDeF" "ASDFGh")
```

Then when you want to call them, use

```
curl -L --silent --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=${tokens[0]}"
```

And if you want to add a token you can

```
tokens+=("qwerty")
```

Comment: That sounds like it will work, thanks! Where would the array go in relevance of the script?

Comment: The array can go anywhere as long as it is set before the curl is called, otherwise there will be no value for ${tokens[0]}.

Comment: a different token, in case there were more than one tokens that you needed to store